# MultiDataTrigger Binding to Collection and To a property within the collection

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, multitrigger

I have the following XAML:

```
<Style.Triggers>

  <MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsCountConverter}}">
        <Condition.Value>True</Condition.Value>
      </Condition> 
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Errors[0].HasError}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
  </MultiDataTrigger>

</Style.Triggers>
```

Errors is a `ObservableCollection<BrokenRule>`. The BrokenRule has a property called HasError. Now, I want to bind to that HasError property but not sure how to reference it in XAML.

Comment: Your XAML appears correct: you can use the indexer syntax to get at the first BrokenRule of the collection, then .HasError will get you to that BrokenRule's HasError property.  What's the problem you're seeing?  What data binding errors are you seeing in the Output window?

Comment: The Errors collection includes the broken rules for the whole ViewModel. Can you explain the indexer syntax. I used .[0].HasError but then it did not display anything.

Comment: BTW I don't see any errors. The Errors is a List<BrokenRule> which contains the broken rules for the entire view model.

Comment: The indexer syntax is what you have: `[n]`.  In your case, where the collection is `Errors`, you'd use `Errors[0]` and hence `Errors[0].HasError`.  Note it is just `Errors[0]` as in your XAML; you do NOT need a `.` prefix as in your `.[0]` comment.

Comment: Actually my technique will not work as I expected. As, Errors will be invoked twice once for each TextBox. I cannot increment [0] to [1]. Anyways, I will try to implement a new solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively unknown forward-slash syntax for accessing a collection's current item. so if you want to bind to the current item of a data source you'd use `"{Binding Path=/}"` since you seem to want to automatically increment your Errors collection and have HasError respond accordingly you'd should be able to use something like `"{Binding Path=Errors/HasError}"` to get the HasErrors property of the current item in Errors.

Hope that helps!